# Can't store php session to another directory

Tags: php, session, configuration

Help me please with php session.

I have php 5.5.21 on my server.

And i have users and admins.

Users sessions i save to default session directory, but admins to another (to provide longer lifetime).

My problem that i can't store session for admin to another directory, and it die more faster than i need.

```
<?php

function isAdmin()
{
    return true;
}
$path = session_save_path(); // /var/lib/php5
if (isAdmin()) {
    $ttl = 36000;
    $path .= '/sessionAdmin';
} else {
    $ttl = 1440;
    $path .= '/session';
}
session_save_path($path);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $ttl);
ini_set('session.cache_expire', $ttl);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);
session_start();
```

Moreover i added this directories to open_basedir `'/var/www/vhosts/site.com:/usr/share/pear:/var/lib/php5/session:/var/lib/php5/sessionAdmin'`

but it doesn't help me, and all new sessions saves at directory `/var/lib/php5`

not at `/var/lib/php5/sessionAdmin`.

Comment: Did you checked the permission on the directory's?

Comment: does your sessions (for user and admin) get saved to /var/lib/php5 or /var/lib/php5/session or /var/lib/php5/sessionAdmin ?

Comment: always /var/lib/php5

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

In settings to my virtual host were:

`php_admin_value session.save_path /var/lib/php5`

and accordingly to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php):

*Any directive type set with php_admin_value can not be overridden by .htaccess or ini_set().*

I delete this setting from virtual host and all become works correctly.

Thanks everyone for help!!!